# How to choose a part of the data based on a specific period of date-time?

Tags: r

I have a data named 'mydata' like below,

```
Time                    V1     V2
07/08/2020 18:47:58     0.2    0.3
07/08/2020 19:47:58     0.7    0.8
07/08/2020 20:00:00     0.2    0.3
07/08/2020 21:00:00     0.6    0.9
07/08/2020 22:00:00     0.2    0.3
07/08/2020 23:00:00     0.5    0.7
08/08/2020 1:00:00      0.4    0.3
08/08/2020 2:00:00      0.5    0.9
08/08/2020 5:00:00      0.7    0.1
08/08/2020 7:00:00      0.4    0.3
```

I want to choose a part of the data based on the 'Time' column. The ideal selected data should like below,

```
 Time                    V1     V2
07/08/2020 22:00:00     0.2    0.3
07/08/2020 23:00:00     0.5    0.7
08/08/2020 1:00:00      0.4    0.3
08/08/2020 2:00:00      0.5    0.9
08/08/2020 5:00:00      0.7    0.1
```

I tried to change the 'Time' column from character to POSIXct variables first, then use the 'with' function to subtract the needed period data, but it doesn't work.

```
mydata$date_time<-as.POSIXct(maydata$Time, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Hope someone could help!

Comment: What is the actual date/time range which you are trying to target here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen From 07/08/2020 22:00:00 to 08/08/2020 5:00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just convert to times and filter using subsetting square brackets:

```r
df$Time <- strptime(df$Time, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

df[df$Time > as.POSIXct("2020-08-07 21:05:00") &
   df$Time < as.POSIXct("2020-08-08 06:00:00"),]
#>                   Time  V1  V2
#> 6  2020-08-07 22:00:00 0.2 0.3
#> 7  2020-08-07 23:00:00 0.5 0.7
#> 8  2020-08-08 01:00:00 0.4 0.3
#> 9  2020-08-08 02:00:00 0.5 0.9
#> 10 2020-08-08 05:00:00 0.7 0.1
```

---

**Data**

```r
df <- structure(list(Time = c("07/08/2020 18:47:58", "07/08/2020 19:47:58", 
"07/08/2020 20:00:00", "07/08/2020 21:00:00", "07/08/2020 22:00:00", 
"07/08/2020 23:00:00", "08/08/2020 1:00:00", "08/08/2020 2:00:00", 
"08/08/2020 5:00:00", "08/08/2020 7:00:00"), V1 = c(0.2, 0.7, 
0.2, 0.6, 0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7, 0.4), V2 = c(0.3, 0.8, 0.3, 
0.9, 0.3, 0.7, 0.3, 0.9, 0.1, 0.3)), row.names = 2:11, class = "data.frame")

df
#>                   Time  V1  V2
#> 2  07/08/2020 18:47:58 0.2 0.3
#> 3  07/08/2020 19:47:58 0.7 0.8
#> 4  07/08/2020 20:00:00 0.2 0.3
#> 5  07/08/2020 21:00:00 0.6 0.9
#> 6  07/08/2020 22:00:00 0.2 0.3
#> 7  07/08/2020 23:00:00 0.5 0.7
#> 8   08/08/2020 1:00:00 0.4 0.3
#> 9   08/08/2020 2:00:00 0.5 0.9
#> 10  08/08/2020 5:00:00 0.7 0.1
#> 11  08/08/2020 7:00:00 0.4 0.3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

We can use `between`

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
     filter(between(dmy_hms(Time), as.POSIXct("2020-08-07 21:05:00"), 
          as.POSIXct("2020-08-08 06:00:00")))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Time = c("07/08/2020 18:47:58", "07/08/2020 19:47:58", 
"07/08/2020 20:00:00", "07/08/2020 21:00:00", "07/08/2020 22:00:00", 
"07/08/2020 23:00:00", "08/08/2020 1:00:00", "08/08/2020 2:00:00", 
"08/08/2020 5:00:00", "08/08/2020 7:00:00"), V1 = c(0.2, 0.7, 
0.2, 0.6, 0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7, 0.4), V2 = c(0.3, 0.8, 0.3, 
0.9, 0.3, 0.7, 0.3, 0.9, 0.1, 0.3)), row.names = 2:11, class = "data.frame")
```